# why is $\{x\mid f(x)=\infty\}$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

why is $\{x\mid f(x)=\infty\}$ measurable?

I know that $\{x\mid f(x)=a\}$ is measurable when a is finite. But textbooks rarely mention $\{x\mid f(x)=\infty\}$. It seems to be the opposite from the definitions of measurable. But how to show that $\{x\mid f(x)=\infty\}$ is measurable?

Comment: $\cap_n \{ x | f(x) >n \}$.

Comment: What is your definition of measurable?

Comment: What are the range and domain of $f$? If $f$ is a real-valued function, then $f(x)$ can never equal $\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left\{x\mid f(x)=\infty\right\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left\{x\mid f(x)\ge n\right\}$$

Comment: That looks like nonsense to me.

Comment: @TonyK: In the context of measure theory, it is often assumed that one works with functions taking values in the extended real number line, which gives the above sets meaning.